# Highlight empty lines at beginning and end of file and more than one empty lines

Tags: vim

In vim, I would like to highlight empty lines at beginning and end of file, and more than one consecutive line. Example:

```
--- start of file
.
an empty line just before this line (at the beginning of the file)
more than one empty line will follow
.
.
empty lines at the end of file will follow
.
.
--- end of file
```

In the example above, the lines with a dot should be highlighted.

I've tried to match the lines with the following expression, unfortunately without luck:

```
call matchadd('EmptyLines', '\n\s\*\n\s\*\n')
```

How can I match all of these lines and highlight them (preferably the whole line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special regular expression atoms `\%^` ([`:help start-of-file`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#start-of-file)) and `\%$` ([`:help end-of-file`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#end-of-file)) will help here. With them, you can match empty lines at the boundaries of the buffer, like this:

```
call matchadd('EmptyLines', '\%^\n\+')
call matchadd('EmptyLines', '^\n\+\%$')
```

Unfortunately, there are some **limitations**:

- You can only match what's there, which is not much in empty lines. Vim will just highlight a single cell width (that represents the newline character).
- In the very last line, nothing is highlighted at all. If you want to see any indication of a single empty final line, you could drop the `^` from the pattern. Then, the empty trailing line would be indicated by highlighting before that line.

#### Implementation alternatives

Using [`:help signs`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/sign.txt.html#signs), you can highlight the full width of empty lines, and have an additional indication in the *sign column*. The downside is that you can't simply define a pattern for signs. You have to explicitly place them on certain lines, and adapt this position whenever the buffer contents change. That would mean defining some `:autocmd`s, and living with either poor performance or accepting short delays until the signs update. (They are meant to be used for things like marking build errors that don't change so often and only on demand.)

---

Instead of a visual indication, if your goal is to avoid having those empty lines, you could also hook into the `BufWrite` event and either print a warning or completely abort the `:write` if such lines are found. My [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967) does this (but for whitespace at the end of individual lines).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I came up with the following commands thanks to your information: `call matchadd('EvilWhitespace', '\%^\(\n\s*\)\+')` (empty lines at beginning of the file with optional whitespace), `call matchadd('EvilWhitespace', '\n\zs\s*\(\n\s*\)\{2,\}')` (consecutive empty lines with optional whitespace) and `call matchadd('EvilWhitespace', '^\(\n\s*\)\+\%$')` (empty lines at the end of the file with optional whitespace). Maybe you want to add it to your answer for reference?
Also, thanks for mentioning your DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin.